# Access parameter query not returning records with specific value

Tags: ms-access, select, parameters

Yesterday I asked a similar question, and thank you to those who replied.  I'm creating this new question as I've worked a few things out and can hopefully provide more/better information, but still running into the same problem.  I'm very, very new to Access and any kind of code or related terms so thank you in advance for your patience with me.

I'm building a query to search tbl: Inventory.  There are no lookups built into the table.  The parameters can be entered via combo boxes on a form by the user.  The row sources for the combo boxes are distinct values from the coordinating fields in tbl: Inventory.  I want the user to be able to fill in any/all parameters and get results, so I'm using `LIKE "*"` in my criteria of each parameter.  All values in the parameters are text.  In tbl: Inventory the fields are also all text (except the PK which is an autonumber).  This is my SQL for the query:

```
SELECT Inventory.InventoryID, Inventory.SetID, Inventory.ItemName, Inventory.Period, Inventory.Color, Inventory.GarmentType, Inventory.GarmentSubType, Inventory.ATCShow
FROM Inventory
WHERE (((Inventory.Period) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearchInventory]![cboPeriod] & "*") AND ((Inventory.Color) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearchInventory]![cboColor] & "*") AND ((Inventory.GarmentType) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearchInventory]![cboType] & "*") AND ((Inventory.GarmentSubType) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearchInventory]![cboSubType] & "*") AND ((Inventory.ATCShow) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearchInventory]![cboShow] & "*"));
```

Please excuse the excess brackets, as I said, very new so I'm letting Access do most of the writing for me.

For some reason, no matter what combination of parameters are used, it will not return any records where Inventory.GarmentType = suit coat, and the record also includes a SetID--even if the only parameter entered is "suit coat".  For records that do not include a setID and are type=suit coat, the record is returned. If the record includes a setID and is not a suit coat, the record is returned.  Not sure if that is related, as SetID is not a parameter, but it's something I noticed.

I've tried changing "*" to "%" and LIKE to ALIKE and no records at all were returned.

Any ideas?  Happy to provide any additional information.  Thank you!

Comment: Suggest posting to a forum that allows attaching files. Really need to review db to analyze this issue. Because need to see raw data. I don't use dynamic queries. I prefer VBA to conditionally build filter criteria and apply to form or report. However, I expect same issue will be encountered because appears to be something odd about data, not methods.

Comment: @June7 is there a forum that you would recommend?

Comment: accessforums.net, utteraccess.com, access-programmers.co.uk

Comment: @June7 Thank you!